# Will my report on Social Studio be affected if I deactivate its owner?

Tags: reporting, social-studio

User (A) has created a Post Report on Social Studio that is sent weekly to user (B). I want to deactivate user (A), but I want to know if that will affect the report? Will it still remain active and run on schedule?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past they did keep running , so as to recheck I ran a quick test in my internal account and I can give a clear answer that the report still works and sends even if you deactivate the User !

Hope this Helps !

Comment: thank you very much!!